# Why am I getting error while importing a module in kaggle?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, kaggle

I am working on a kaggle notebook. I tried to import bs4 but its showing error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'**

My internet is on in kaggle settings. What is the solution?

Comment: *Before* importing a module you need to *install* it first.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you should try to install the module first.

Create a cell at the beginning of the notebook and type:

```
!pip install bs4
```

Then you should be able to import the module.

Comment: ok thank you. I am new to kaggle so I thought that install in an online platform is not required.